# JavaScript AJAX Request Library for Browsers that Supports Cookies

Tags: ajax, browser, request

I am looking for a JavaScript AJAX request library for browsers that also supports cookies. I tried broswer-request but apparently it does not support cookies.

Any suggestions?

It is also better if it is available for NodeJS through NPM for server side.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `jQuery`'s functions `$.post`, `$.get`, and `$.ajax` for the ajax requests. You can also edit cookies with jQuery, if you use this plugin.

[StackOverFlow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1458728/2280505)

[Link to file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/src/jquery.cookie.js)

Comment: I will receive the cookie from the server and I need the AJAX library to be able to utilize the cookie in subsequent requests. Does jQuery support this?

Comment: In the php file, I would imagine you can just use `setcookie()`, but if not, have the php file echo the cookie info, set a callback function in the request, pass the `echo`ed data into that function, and set the cookie with javascript. See http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp